# MKMapView not transitioning properly

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, mkmapview

I've a MKMapView as a child view of another UIView called `mainView`. If I transition my `mainView` on the y-axis with:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
    CGRect frame = self.mainView.frame;
    frame.origin.y += 100.0f;
    self.mainView.frame = frame;
} completion:nil];
```

then the `mainView` and all it's subviews nicely transition down the screen by 100 points, except of the MKMapView, which stays exactly at the original position.

So I tried another experiment and also moved the `frame.origin.y` of the MKMapView, which then actual moves the map view, but not synchronized with the other views (it has a slight delay).

Anyone an idea why that is? I assume because MKMapView is not a direct `UIView` subclass. Is there a way to fix this behavior?

Comment: Are you trying this in the simulator?  I've been having some weird resizing issues when resizing maps in the simulator.  Works fine on the device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Fixed.** The problem was the `autoresizesSubviews` property of the parent `UIView` which was set to `YES` by default and causes a strange behavior with the `MKMapView`. Setting `autoresizesSubviews` to `NO` makes it work like a charm :-)

Comment: Yes thank you! it is acting strange since the last month. For the people facing the same problem, also check your `Storyboard -> Select the view -> 'Show attributes inspector' in utilities` and uncheck Autoresize Subviews''